# How to set the selected value of an MVC5 DropDownList?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Given the following MVC5 code:

```
@Html.DropDownList(name: "Enhanced_Rijndael_AlgorithmID", optionLabel: null, selectList: EnhancedRijndaelAvailableHashAlgorithmList.Select(item => new SelectListItem
{
    Value = item.RecordID.ToString(),
    Text = item.HashAlgorithm,
    Selected = "select" == item.RecordID.ToString()
}), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Is it possible to set the "selected value" of this list?

The only thing I can think of is somehow setting the Selected value in the `SelectListItem` set.

Comment: Do you have a view model for the view, then use `Html.DropDownListFor` helper method.

Comment: I wasn't sure that the `DropDownListFor` would work with the SelectListItem I was using. Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the what Ive come up with after being reminded of the `DropDownListFor`

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(expression: r => r.AlgorithmID, selectList: EnhancedRijndaelAvailableHashAlgorithmList.Select(item => new SelectListItem
{
    Value = item.RecordID.ToString(),
    Text = item.HashAlgorithm,
    Selected = "select" == item.RecordID.ToString()
}),
htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" }, optionLabel: "Algorithm")
```